# Cannot get icon asset register to display for iPhone after originally setting up for just iPad

Tags: swift, xcode, assets, appicon

I'm writing an app that was originally just for iPad but now needs to be for phones too. I went to the Deployment info in General setup and changed it from iPad to Universal. However, when I went to the App icons and launch images and selected the App icons source in the Asset Register it only shows iPad

How can I reset it to display iPhone icons too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your xcasset catalog, select `AppIcon` and bring Utilities panel with Cmd+Alt+0, there you can check `iPhone` and new empty entries foer iPhone icon sizes should appear inside of `AppIcon`

[image: Cmd+Alt+0]